# How to instantiate a type without Activator.CreateInstance / reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

I had a bit of trouble coming up with the title for this but consider the following code:

```
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public SomeClass(IEnumerable<IInterface> contracts)
        {
            _contracts = contracts;
        }

        private readonly IEnumerable<IInterface> _contracts;

        public TService GetValueInstance<TService>(string name)
            where TService : class
        {
            var contract = _contracts.First(x => x.ToString() == name);
            var type = contract.Types[typeof(TService)];
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            return instance as TService;
        }
    }

    public class InterfaceImplementation : IInterface
    {
        public Dictionary<Type, Type> Types => new Dictionary<Type, Type>
        {
            { typeof(Key), typeof(Value)}
        };

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return nameof(InterfaceImplementation);
        }
    }

    public interface IInterface
    {
        Dictionary<Type, Type> Types { get; }
    }

    public class Key
    {
    }

    public class Value
    {
    }
```

All highly contrived, focus on the bit with Activator.CreateInstance. Assume the IEnumerable 'contracts' is injected.

**Q**: Is there any way I can create registrations in Autofac so I can remove Activator.CreateInstance and somehow return the instantiated type directly?

InterfaceImplementation.Types property needs to stay.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean `directly`? what you're looking for SOUNDS like `Service locator pattern`, if you google that it is easy to do with Autofac - basically you inject a `container` (or whatever they're called in Autofac, can't remember) and then ask the `container` give me this type.

But these serve completely different purposes.
`Activator.CreateInstance` is used to create POCO models usually, not services. And ServiceLocator is used to locate services with their dependencies (hence the name).

What types of objects are you trying to create?

Comment: This would return a service. I know I could resolve from the container but was trying to avoid that.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid that? i mean how would it work if you don't want to create it nor you want to resolve it? what is the problem?

Comment: it looks to me that your `SomeClass` plays role as another real container (which can resolve for some instance from some name by `GetValueInstance`. So why not use the DI container directly in this case? Your `SomeClass` can wrap a container, use that container to resolve anything. The `name` can be used as filtering condition only, meaning if it belongs to the `contracts`, the wrapped container will be used to resolve for some instance, otherwise `null` will be returned.

Comment: by the way, internally any instance created from just `Type` will involve either `Activator.CreateInstance` or reflection. There is no way to by-pass that. DI container just blinds you from seeing that. If you don't rely on some already-built container, your class is actually some kind of container (without any `Register` method?). So creating any instance should be its own responsibility (meaning cannot avoid using reflection or `Activator.CreateInstance`)

Comment: After a bit of thoughts, decided to resolve from the container instance. I think that's ok.